# Tesseract OCR word-dawg not including in combine_tessdata

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract ocr to train a new language for my final year project.

I created word-dawg from my wordlists. 
But the combine_tessdata result is the same whether I include the word-dawg and wordlist or nor. So I am not sure if my word-dawg and wordlist are included in my training data.

The output is as follow:
Offset for type 0 is -1
Offset for type 1 is 140
Offset for type 2 is 3726
Offset for type 3 is 3904
Offset for type 4 is 346848
Offset for type 5 is 347329
Offset for type 6 is -1
Offset for type 7 is -1
Offset for type 8 is -1
Offset for type 9 is -1
Offset for type 10 is -1
Offset for type 11 is -1
Offset for type 12 is -1
Offset for type 13 is 354078
Offset for type 14 is -1
Offset for type 15 is -1
Offset for type 16 is -1

I believe offset 2 is for unicharambigs.
Any idea which offset is for word-dawg? 
And how about the rest of the offset?

Answer (score 1):

Could be a file name issue. Below is the output from my training. "-1" means file not exist.

```
Combining tessdata files
Output vie.traineddata created sucessfully.
TessdataManager combined tesseract data files.
Offset for type  0 (vie.config                ) is -1
Offset for type  1 (vie.unicharset            ) is 140
Offset for type  2 (vie.unicharambigs         ) is 15877
Offset for type  3 (vie.inttemp               ) is 21397
Offset for type  4 (vie.pffmtable             ) is 1466247
Offset for type  5 (vie.normproto             ) is 1468147
Offset for type  6 (vie.punc-dawg             ) is -1
Offset for type  7 (vie.word-dawg             ) is 1513182
Offset for type  8 (vie.number-dawg           ) is -1
Offset for type  9 (vie.freq-dawg             ) is 1589568
Offset for type 10 (vie.fixed-length-dawgs    ) is -1
Offset for type 11 (vie.cube-unicharset       ) is -1
Offset for type 12 (vie.cube-word-dawg        ) is -1
Offset for type 13 (vie.shapetable            ) is 1594178
Offset for type 14 (vie.bigram-dawg           ) is -1
Offset for type 15 (vie.unambig-dawg          ) is -1
Offset for type 16 (vie.params-training-model ) is -1
```

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: At the same time, do you happen to know what are the values inside inttemp file?  So there are 8 colums which look something like this - 3400 0000 fbff ffff 0200 0000 3400 0000. What does each column represent?